# <<END like construct in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a big chunk of HTML which is a template for some data added using AJAX.  I would like to store the chunk in a variable and then do replacements on tokens in it but I don't want to mess up the formatting of the html to get it into a javascript string.  Is there a thing like the

```
<<END
```

command in perl which will read everything following into a string until it hits the end token?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, unfortunately, there is no such construct in JavaScript.

You have a few different options, each with its own merits:

1. #### String concatenation

   :

   ```
   var html = '<div id="something">' +
                  '<p>Lots of HTML</p>' +
                  '<p>Lots of HTML</p>' +
                  '<p>Lots of HTML</p>' +
              '</div>';
   ```
2. #### Escaping the **`newline`**

   :

   ```
   var html = '<div id="something">\
                  <p>Lots of HTML</p>\
                  <p>Lots of HTML</p>\
                  <p>Lots of HTML</p>\
               </div>';
   ```
3. #### Array joining

   :

   ```
   var html = [
       '<div id="something">',
           '<p>Lots of HTML</p>',
           '<p>Lots of HTML</p>',
           '<p>Lots of HTML</p>',
       '</div>'
   ].join('');
   ```
4. #### Storing it in an arbitrary hidden element

   :

   HTML:

   ```
   <textarea id="template" style="display:none;">
       <div id="something">
           <p>Lots of HTML</p>
           <p>Lots of HTML</p>
           <p>Lots of HTML</p>
       </div>
   </textarea>
   ```

   JavaScript:

   ```
   var html = document.getElementById('template').value;
   ```

   I prefer using `<script type="text/html">`s or HTML comments but `<textarea>`s seem to be quite popular.
5. #### Using a full-on templating engine such as

   :

   - **http://embeddedjs.com/**
   - **http://jtemplates.tpython.com/**
   - Also see: **http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/**

Comment: Me too, though I'm curious about textarea vs. div.  I've always used div's.

Comment: The textarea trick can be a bad idea: it will be visible to any visitor reading the page without applying CSS. One such visitor is Googlebot...

Comment: @Nick, that's why I tend to use <!-- HTML comments -->

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: no.

Since you're already doing AJAX calls, why not also retrieve the template via AJAX too - probably the simplest way to get it into a JS variable.

Answer (score 0):

The language itself doesn't provide anything for this.  I have used [EJS (Embedded Javascript Templates)](http://embeddedjs.com/) to solve a similar problem in the past, though.  It was easy to work with, and uses a programming model that should be familiar to most web programmers.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing in vanilla JavaScript. And I don't believe there's an implementation of that statement in jQuery either.

But it should be easy to implement with a simple extension method on the String prototype.

Or you could just implement [Jogn Resig's micro templating solution](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) (he's the guy who created and maintains jQuery).